# frequent item filter in array using ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, user-defined-functions

```
total =["a","a","a","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","c","c","c","d","d","d","d","d","d","d","d","b","b","e","e","e","e","e","f"]

smart_total = total.group_by{|i| i}.map{|i,j| [i,j.length]}
smart_total = [["a", 3], ["b", 10], ["c", 3], ["d", 8], ["e", 5], ["f", 1]]
```

I have the sample array

```
sample1 = ["a","f","b"]
```

depending on the max frequent item, the final output should one single element, here its `b`

```
sample2 = ["a","c"]
```

the output here can be either `a` or `c`

I am looking for something like

```
result1 = sample1.magik_function
=>"b"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sample1.max_by{|c| total.count(c)} # => "b"
sample2.max_by{|c| total.count(c)} # => "a"
```